# geiser-eval-buffer switch to different frame

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

I am trying out geiser and after evaluating it always switch to different frame with different buffer than my source code. Could this be prevented? Is it possible to stay after pressing C-c C-b in my current buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean it switches to a different *window*? If so, you may want to check out the variables `geiser-debug-jump-to-debug-p` and `geiser-debug-show-debug-p`, which control changing focus to the `* Geiser dbg *` buffer and showing it at all, respectively.